# Do humans, pets and livestock drastically outweigh all other land mammals?

Tags: population

Does this picture demonstrate the actual proportions well (from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1338/))?

[image]

Comment: The image references its source, if you read the gray letters at the bottom: [Vaclav Smil: The Earth's Biosphere: Evolution, Dynamics, and Change](http://www.amazon.com/The-Earths-Biosphere-Evolution-Dynamics/dp/0262692988)

Comment: It's pretty safe to assume that an XKCD infographic is accurate.  That said, there's no harm in being skeptical - that's what we're here for.

Comment: @Suma The source doesn't seem to be an original research and I don't know how reputable it is as well.